# Las luces pasan a traves de los objetos en unity

Tags: unity3d

Estoy haciendo un juego con una escena oscura, por lo tanto estoy agregando luces, pero, al agregarlas, me doy cuenta que las luces pasan a traves de mis objetos, tengo un escenario hecho en blender, importado como FBX, he intentado usar probuilder, pero igual sigue pasando...

Nota: estoy usando Universal Render Pipeline

[image: luz pasando a traves de una pared]

Comment: Bienvenido. Necesitas mostrar un [example]. Si no podemos reproducir el problema es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: olvide agregar una captura de pantalla, lo siento, ya acabo de editar

Comment: Si, la imagen concuerda con lo que describes. Pero necesitamos más información. Por ejemplo, qué configuración tiene el objeto de la luz que ves atravesando las paredes.